# Best book for statistical inference (Self-study)

Tags: self-study, references

I want to develop some skills in statistical inference for a career in data science or machine learning. I purchased the book "All of Statistics" which is a good book, but there are not answer keys online, which makes it difficult to check whether or not I am doing things correctly. Can anyone suggest books that are similar, but have exercise answers available.

Comment: A number of related threads can be found by searching for posts bearing the [tag:references] tag.

Comment: As @Sycorax pointed out, there are several threads on similar topics. The book you choose will also depend on your level of mathematical expertise and what you want out of the book.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working through a masters thesis in wildlife sciences, with some heavy statistics. Browsed quite a few books but found this one the most intuitive: 
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/1461471370/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

"An Introduction to Statistical Learning: with Applications in R" by Gareth James et al. 2017

Getting into R seems the way to go as well. At least for ecology. It's really taken over all the statistical software being used in this field.